# Can't add content on pages using webform template in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, templates, webforms, umbraco, master-pages

I am using umbraco 7 and i'm not really good on MVC, so i am using webforms and when i try to use a webform template i can't add content on the page, just on the template.

Here i use in de default.master file the contentplace holder like this:

```
<div id="mainContent">
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </div>
```

Then i create the template called "Text Webform" and this is the code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/umbraco/Masterpages/Default.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    This content is displayed

    Am i forgetting some code to add here?

</asp:Content>
```

[Click on this to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uefcD.png)

The problem is when i try to add content in a page that is using "Text Webform" template, that content is not displayed, as you can see on the screenshots [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgBFG.png)

I'm sure i need to add some content in the Text Webform template but i don't know exactly what and i'm desperate, please somebody provide any help,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define what fields (eg properties from your document type) to show where in your template. I believe this is what you are looking for? https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Masterpages/umbracoitem - just

Comment: That's for displaying document properties which is good, but i only want to add content in the content page that is using that template, but this content is not being displayed.. i'm still lost on this so please anybody can help me?

Comment: No, inside the asp:Content tag you add the umbraco:item and point it to the relevant property of the template - if you have a content field with the alias bodyText, that's what you point to. Everything in a document type is a property. The template will then work with Umbraco to show the right content on the right page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now i can explain it better,

I just want the equal function to @CurrentPage.GetGridHtml("content", "fanoe") using a webform template..

Comment: And as I've explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558977/display-grid-value-using-webforms-in-umbraco that might not be possible. Can we agree that I did indeed answer the question you asked here?